Why did Umar ra say this to hafsa ra
The full hadith is here
enter link description here
My question is about these parts of the hadith

don't be tempted to imitate your neighbor (i.e. `Aisha) in her behavior towards the Prophet), for she (i.e. Aisha) is more beautiful than you, and more beloved to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ).


I then said, 'I went to Hafsa and said to her: Do not be tempted to imitate your companion (`Aisha) for she is more beautiful than you and more beloved to the Prophet.' The Prophet (ﷺ) smiled again.

What did Umar ra intend by saying this to Hafsa ra and why did the Prohet SAW ?

Isn't the context present in the hadith? What don't you get?

I don’t really understand what aisha ra had to really do with the issue and why it matter that she was more beautiful or beloved to the prophet
